# Java choosing between two numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method where you choose 2 number in main and the method finds the highest value between does to numbers.

The program takes a number divides it by 2, if not possible to divide multiply by 3 and add 1, divide again and so on until reaching 1.

output: number 10
6 times

```
int count = 0;
  while( number != 1){

    count++;

    if(number % 2 == 0){
    number = number / 2;
    }else{

    number = number * 3 + 1;

   }
}

 return count;
```

This is what i have so far and i have no idea how to pick 2 number and finding the highest one in between those 2.

Comment: Just a heads up, you may want to fix the formatting in your post- make sure *all* your code is formatted correctly (the first line and last few lines aren't displayed as code at the moment)

Comment: what about the `max` function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.util.Random` for generating random values.

```
Random r = new Random();
int n1 = r.nextInt();
int n2 = r.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put what you have in a method that takes an int as a parameter, you can call it twice, once using a java.util.Random - generated number, and again using a different random value. You can store the results of both calls as ints, and compare the two of them. Hope that helps!

```
int first = reduceNumber(r.nextInt());
int second = reduceNumber(r.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Random class to generate random numbers.
To know the maximum of them,

```
int max = Math.max(n1, n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. Those to numbers are pick by me in main. I think i have to use array. 
So the output should be like this:
Using Scanner in main.

lowest limit: 2
highest limit: 10000000
the number 837799(method that finds the number) is the one that is divided
the most times: 524(code that counts how many times it has been divided) which i have..

That's how it's suppose to look like. So i don't think random is going to help.